# Tapestry : no pop up error

Tags: css, tapestry

I'm working on a Tapestry project.
Before, when I forgot a field in a form, I got a beautiful mistake in a pop-up. But since I imported jQuery, the errors are not in pop-up, but next to the fields.

This is my import :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.got5</groupId>
  <artifactId>tapestry5-jquery</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>apache-staging</id>
  <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>devlab722-repo</id>
  <url>http://nexus.devlab722.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases
  </url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>

<repository>
    <id>devlab722-snapshot-repo</id>
    <url>http://nexus.devlab722.net/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
    </url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

Does anyone had this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21topic/tapestry5-jquery/jqHyY0JCz-c

In the AppModule.java, I added this :

```
    configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "false");
    configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.JQUERY_ALIAS, "$j");
```

in the contributeApplicationDefaults function

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you liked the Tapestry error popups from prior releases ... I suspect you are the only one who liked them; I'm afraid once you upgrade to 5.4 they are gone for good.